# Start AWS java Lambda function from another Lambda function asynchronously

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, lambda

My goal is to start a Lambda function from within another Lambda function. Specifically I want the 2nd function to start, leaving the 1st function to finish independently of the 2nd. No response needs to be returned to the 1st function.

I have spent a lot of time looking at examples as well as the AWS documentation.

I am able to successfully start the 2nd function but cannot get it run independently of the first. The 1st function always waits for the 2nd one to finish before it finishes.

I use thise code:

```
AWSLambdaAsync lambda = AWSLambdaAsyncClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).build();
    InvokeRequest req = new InvokeRequest().withFunctionName(functionName).withPayload(jsonStuff);
    // req.setInvocationType(InvocationType.Event);

    Future<InvokeResult> future_res = lambda.invokeAsync(req);
```

This does not start the 2nd function (with or without setting the invocation type).

If I include this code:

```
try {
        InvokeResult thisResult = future_res.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then the second function is fired but the first function waits for the second to finish before it continues.

How do I start the second function without having to wait for it to complete. At present it ads 2 seconds to the time taken for the first function to complete (the first function, without starting the second, takes 4 seconds to complete).

Comment: Refer this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html#API_Invoke_RequestSyntax. Set the InvocationType to Event. By default, the Invoke API assumes RequestResponse invocation type.

Answer (score 1):

You could publish a message to Amazon SNS. When you go to configure the topic select AWS Lambda and put in the ARN of the lambda to trigger.

There's even an [Amazon How To for triggering Lambda from SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda.html).

This is personally what I would do: there's a little more infrastructure here, but it even further separates the concerns of Lambda A and Lambda B (because what if, 6 months from now, you realize Lambda B has to be a traditional microservice? Easy: just reconfigure the SNS topic. Lambda A doesn't have to know).

Comment: thanks very much. i tried it but can't get it to work. i think my problem is the json format of the message (jsonStuff) i pass when calling publish: snsClient.publish("arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:xxxx...xxxx", jsonStuff); - any hints on where i can see examples (in java)? thanks

Comment: managed to figure it out. need to create a lambda function that receives an SNS event as the input type. then pass json input message as string (using Gson) to convert.